# How to import css with webpack?

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue.js

**TWO PART QUESTION**

My steps:

1. Created empty folder
2. opend `cmd`
3. navigate to folder and run `npm init -f`
4. run `vue init webpack`
5. run `npm install`
6. npm `i bootstrap-vue`
7. npm `run dev`

my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

webpack.base.conf.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
            config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            '@': resolve('src'),
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: vueLoaderConfig
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            },
            { //this rule will only be used for any vendors
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                include: [/node_modules/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                exclude: [/node_modules/] //add this line so we ignore css coming from node_modules
            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

when I run this I get:

> Module build failed: Unknown word (5:1)

[image]

**Part 2:**

After some time found a solution to the above problem by installing a loader package and changin my main.js to this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'


import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

this solved my first problem **BUT**:

If i try to add a local css file like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'


import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './content/bootstrapGrid.css'

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

I again get the same error:

> Module build failed: Unknown word (5:1)

[image]

I am new to webpack, vue and the entire SPA. 
Been at this for a while now and im stuck, anyone that can see what I am missing?

Comment: I always compile my css seperately, but I think you may need to add `css!` before your css file: `import 'css!./content/bootstrapGrid.css'`

Comment: trying that i get: This dependency was not found:

* css!./content/bootstrapGrid.css in ./src/main.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save css!./content/bootstrapGrid.css

Comment: @craig_h you gave me an idea: import '!style-loader!css-loader!./content/bootstrapGrid.css'; this worked but I would still like to know why the first attempt did not work

Comment: @craig_h Edit: if you are able I would be happy if you are willing to share how exactly you "complie the css seperately"

Comment: Sure, I don't use webpack for css at all, instead I use [clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) with [gulp](https://gulpjs.com) to compile my css files and simply include it using a style tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**!css-loader**

This is the plain css loader. It will return the css code interpreting the resources inside, but it will not add it to the page.
With this loader @import and url(...) are interpreted like require() and will be resolved.

**!style-loader**

This loader adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a  or  tag.
To inject a  you need to get the content of the css file, and then inject that.

```
require("style!raw!./file.css");
// => add rules in file.css to document
```

But it’s recommended to combine it with the css-loader, as it will interpret all the resources in your css file, instead of just having the raw css. ([Check](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader))

```
require("style!css!./file.css");
// => add rules in file.css to document
```

If you want to add a  to your css file, you need to first have the url to that file, for that you can use the file-loader.

```
require("style/url!file!./file.css");
// => add a <link rel="stylesheet"> to file.css to document
```

Hope this helps!

Refer: [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader), [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader)
A good article on this [here](http://tomasalabes.me/blog/_site/web-development/2016/09/13/Webpack-Series-Part-4.html)